# .htaccess redirect error page problems

Tags: .htaccess

I am using the following code in my .htaccess:

```
    ErrorDocument 404 error_page.php?msg=404
```

When I trigger a 404 error, I get a page that says this:

```
    error_page.php?msg=404
```

Is there something that I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you can pass query strings to the document designated by `ErrorDocument`, Something you can try is using it in conjunction with mod_rewrite:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error-doc-404
ErrorDocument 405 /error-doc-405
ErrorDocument 500 /error-doc-500

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^error-doc-([0-9]{3})$ /error_page.php?msg=$1 [L]
```

---

Since this is in a subdirectory off of the document root, it changes everything.

Say the subdirectory is `/something/`

```
ErrorDocument 404 /something/error-doc-404
ErrorDocument 405 /something/error-doc-405
ErrorDocument 500 /something/error-doc-500

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^error-doc-([0-9]{3})$ /something/error_page.php?msg=$1 [L]
```

Assuming that your `error_page.php` file is actually in the `/something/` subdirectory.

Comment: This does not seem to work. How would I implement it? Do I just add this to my .htaccess file?

Comment: @Ian34 Yeah, it would replace any `ErrorDocument` directives that you already have. This is what I use for dynamically generated error pages.

Comment: Now I get this error and a regular 404 error. "Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

Comment: @Ian34 you need to make sure that's in the proper directory and with proper paths. The above is for the document root, if you want this in a subdirectory's htaccess file, you need to make sure the Rule is in the htaccess in the document root, or remove all the slashes.

Comment: When I remove all the slashes, the page just displays "error-doc-404"

Comment: @Ian34 So I take it you've not put this in your document root like I have?

Comment: @Ian34 That would have been *invaluable* information to have from the start. I've edited the answer for a subdirectory off of the document root.

Comment: Thank you for all the help, I turns out that you can pass query strings to the document designated by ErrorDocument. The whole time, I just had the path incorrect. THanks!